# How to align two headers in the same row?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two headers, an `h1` and `h2` element, in the same row.
I used this code to create a number in a circle which represents the first header and a headline "Device name" which is the second header:

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 45%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0.5px;
  background: #E6354A;
  border: 3px solid #E6354A;
  color: #FDFEFE;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' border-collapse='collapse' style='width:98%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;'>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='4' <div style='clear:both'>
      <div class='circle'>
        <h1 style='font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 0;'>" + obj.value[0].DEVICE_OVERALL_SCORE.toFixed(2) + "</h1>
      </div>
      <h2 style='font-weight: light; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 0;'> Device name: " + grci.name + " </h2>
      </div>
      <hr />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For some reason the circle with the number inside appears in one row and the device name header appears in a row beneath it. Can someone tell me how to make them appear side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to fact that divs and headings are [block elements](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp) by default, which means they take up all of the space and make other block elements have a separate row. To change this, you would require either to `float` them, set them as `flex`, `grid`, or `inline-block` element.

I approached to set them as inline-block since it is the fastest, but it really comes down to requirements.

```
<style>
.circle {border-radius: 45%;width: 30px;height: 20px;padding: 0.5px;background: #E6354A;border: 3px solid #E6354A;color: #FDFEFE;text-align: left;font-size: 5px;}

.circle, h2 {display: inline-block;}
</style>
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' border-collapse ='collapse' style='width:98%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;'>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='4'>
      <div style= 'clear:both'>
        <div class='circle'>
          <h1 style='font-weight: bold; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; margin-top: 0;'>" + obj.value[0].DEVICE_OVERALL_SCORE.toFixed(2) + "</h1>
        </div>
        <h2 style = 'font-weight: light; text-align: left; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 0;'> Device name: " + grci.name + " </h2>
      </div>
      <hr />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! that helped, I also understand the logic now:)

Answer (score 0):

you can't have 2 header side by side at the same time, because the definition of header is a one row at the top of the table. So make sure you use the correct definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the headers in a div and make it flex

```
<style>
  div {
    display: flex;
  }
  h1 {
    widht: 50%;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <h1>HEADER1</h1>
  <h1>HEADER2</h1>
</div>
```

Flex direction is row by default, note that I apply `width: 50%` to create two even columns. You may want to align and justify as well, have a look at  `align-items` and `justify-content` properties.